# ASP WebAPI 2 CSRF tokens

Tags: asp.net-web-api, csrf, csrf-protection, antiforgerytoken

We have a ASP MVC web application, and we also have a WebAPI 2 project to expose actions that would be executed from unkown clients, might be desktop apps, Java websites or whatever.

In the web app we have implemented anti forgery tokens and we want to do it in the web api also.

Reading over the internet it is said that in order to implement anti csrf tokens in web api we have to set two tokens one in the header/cookie and other one in a hidden field.

If we add a view inside the web api project and use the

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

inside a form and submit the post, we can validate the request with

```
AntiForgery.Validate();
```

That's ok and works fine, what I fail to understand is how will, for instance a desktop app, generate a valid request to our web api?

Do we need to expose and action in the api that generates this to tokens and then the client will make the request setting the tokens he just ask for?

Sorry for my english and thanks a lot!